# Can't insert Metro UI CSS into SharePoint Web Part

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, metro-ui-css

I'm trying to insert the following [Metro UI CSS](http://metroui.org.ua/) code into a SharePoint Web Part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/master/docs/css/metro-bootstrap.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/master/min/metro.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="metro">
    <div class="tile bg-cyan"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, whenever I insert the code, the whole webpage becomes distorted (see screenshot below)

[image]

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhe1a8jt/) for the code as well (a simple blue box)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The problem is in the metro.css (In your case bootstrap-metro.css In the new version the bootstrap-metro.css was exchanged with metro.css) refrence file. I couldn't fund the exact roblem, but got this working by removing the unnecessary code from the css file. In my case I was using only the tiles, so I removed pretty much everything except for the classes that contain .tiles, things like @font, @media, and it worked. Good Luck!